# Scala: groovy with analogue

Tags: scala, groovy, syntax

Groovy has awesome syntax sugar called `with`. For example:

```
@groovy.transform.ToString 
class Person {
  String name
  int age
}

def p = new Person()
p.with {
  name = "Joe"
  age  = 10
}

println(p)
```

Output:

```
Person(Joe, 10)
```

Is there any chance to achieve same behavior in Scala?

Yes, I can import all properties of specific variable like this:

```
scala> case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
defined class Person

scala> val p = Person("Joe", 10)
p: Person = Person(Joe,10)

scala> import p._
import p._

scala> name
res0: String = Joe

scala> age
res1: Int = 10
```

But this approach has disadvantages - scope is too wide and I don't want to wrap it into code block

Something similar is described here: http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/08/30/horrible-code/

---

You can try this Groovy code here: [groovyconsole.appspot.com](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5071841047609344)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?
In your first two lines of Scala you have accomplished what you did in Groovy.

Comment: "I don't want to wrap it into code block" - but you did in Groovy.

Comment: That is no "code block".  It's a closure passed to the `with` function.

Comment: @g.krastev I mean I would like to avoid something like https://imgur.com/a/Kbv3R. Partially, it is similar to Groovy syntax

Comment: I fail to see what you gain by using a closure. Saving a few characters? (the difference between `import p._` and `p.with`) Aesthetics? IMHO it's not worth to pay the price with special *magic* syntax.